# CodeContract.Requires(param != null) doesn't prove that param won't be null?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-contracts

Hello
I have a method listed bellow:

```
    public static PasswordCredential Create(string password, string username, string pinCode = null)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password), "Invalid Argument: password");
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username), "Invalid Argument: username");

        PasswordCredential credential = new PasswordCredential();
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        SHA512Managed sha512hasher = new SHA512Managed();


        credential.PasswordHash = sha512hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(password)); <-- Requires unproven: s != null
        credential.Username = username;
        credential.PinCode = pinCode;

        return credential;
    }
```

Does this mean that Contract.Requires doesn't prove the expression? If so what's the use for it? :?

UPDATE

---

Ok, I found a very weird behavior of code contracts. I moved this method to another project and it worked. No more requires unproven warnings. Then I get back to the original project, and in Messages window, I found this line: 
Message 1 CodeContracts: Suggested precondition: Contract.Requires(password != null);
When I double click this item, I'm navigated to PasswordCredential's PinCode property.

```
        [DataMember]
    public string PinCode
    {
        get { return _PinCode; }
        set { _PinCode = value == null ? null : value.Trim(); } <-- I'm navigated here
    }
```

but when I click the warning item, I'm navigated to encoder.GetBytes(password) line.
I don't understand what's wrong. Is it a bug?

Comment: Are you turned on run-time checking? without this it can't work.

Comment: Both runtime and static. Runtime is set tu full

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I copied your code and get no warnings.  If I comment out the `Contract.Requires` for `password`, then I see the same warning.

Comment: Just to be sure, is this exactly the same code that gives you a warning?  No other code between the `Contract.Requires` and the call to `GetBytes`?

Comment: I updated the method with the exact code that gives warning

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why you are getting a warning.  I copied your updated example and don't get a warning unless I comment out the `Contract.Requires`.  I'm using version 1.4.30903.0.

Comment: I agree with adrift, I also do not get any warnings when I copy your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok
There's an issue with CC (which can be reproduced only in my project :D). I sent the project to CC team and got very fast response. They are investigating and probably it will be fixed in the next release.
Anyway thanks for your support guys.